# Loading csv file to Jupyter notebook with readr's read_csv()

Tags: r, csv, jupyter, readr

I am trying to compile a Jupyter notebook with r, but nothing is happening because apparently the file is not getting loaded. What is the correct method of loading a csv file to a Jupyter notebook with r?

Comment: What is the error or warning message you are getting? I used `fread `and `read_csv `and was able to load data without any problem.

Comment: It simply was not doing anything. However, I have already found out why - I did not have the environment set up properly for R, which I have now fixed. Thank you for your input though!